# My app's UI hanged

Tags: android

I am writing an android app, in which I have 1 **button** and 1 **progress bar** as UI elements.

The main aim of this app is when user presses this button, it has to create a database which contains all phone book contacts in customized format, means I am reading Contacts database and manipulating for my requirement.

So I am using **SQLiteOpenHelper** for database operations. I written a method **downloadPhonebook()** to perform all required operations. I written app such that when user presses button I am making progress bar visible and calling this method.

In this case, UI was hanged after clicking button and showing a dialog with **Force Close** and **Wait** buttons, after 15 seconds.

To avoid this I tried following mechanisms.

-> Broadcast Button click message and call method downloadPhonebook(). Here no use, same problem occurred.

-> Used a Thread and AsyncTask to call this method, here I got Runtime exceptions like **Couldn't create Handler inside a Thread, Looper.prepare not called**. I tried calling Looper.prepare() and Looper.loop() even exceptions occurred.

-> I tried with Android Service and Broadcast intent, again same problem UI hanged.

If anybody faced this problem or knows the solution or knows how to use Looper.prepare and Looper.loop please reply me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

the workflow should be something like this: create a handler in your main class, add a handler in your sql helper class, pass the handler from the main class to the sql helper class when you create it. Run the download on separate thread from your main class, when download is ready, call `yourHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0)`. You should override the `Handler.handleMessage` (I'm not sure about the exact name of the method) in your main class. You can also send messages to update the progress, read about [Andoid Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) for more information

Comment: Nothing wrong with my application's SQL part. It is doing as required, the problem was UI hanged even i am calling the blocking method from a receiver.

Comment: I just say to pass a handler from your main class (where it will wait for a Message) and call send the message from the other thread.

Comment: I tried this in a Service, upon receiving button click message in receiver, I am posting same to Handler, there I am calling my method. Here also I am getting UI hang problem.

Comment: what Service, you said "I am writing an android app, in which I have 1 button and 1 progress bar as UI elements." So, when you click the button, how do you pass the handler, where is the handler defined?

Comment: In my question i clearly mentioned (last one), to solve the UI hang problem I used Android Service and Broadcast receiver to handle button click from UI activity.

Comment: you said you have tried, not that you want to use exactly service and Broadcast Reciever. I've mentioned another approach, sorry for misunderstanding